# How to add an ImageView to a custom view class in Android Studio?

Tags: android, view, imageview

Basically I've created a custom class which extends View and what it does currently is drawing a horizontal line where the screen is being touched until it's released. **What I want to achieve is adding an ImageView in the background, behind the line** so that line is drawn in the foreground. Here's the problem as I've got no clue how to add an ImageView to this view despite all the researches.

From my understanding the overriden onDraw function needs to: #1 clear the screen -> #2 draw the image on ImageView -> #3 draw the line on each iteration. I will have to later on implement dynamically image changing on said ImageView if this info helps somehow.

```
public class RateView extends View{

float touchY = (getHeight() / 2);
boolean isPressed = false;
Paint paint=new Paint();

public RateView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context);
    this.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#da5f02"));
    init(null);
}

private void init(AttributeSet attr){
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (isPressed){
            canvas.drawLine(5, touchY, (getWidth()-10), touchY,paint);
        }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent){

    switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            isPressed = true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touchY = motionEvent.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            isPressed = false;
            break;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}}
```

This is my costum view class. My main class only extends AppCompatActivity and sets contentView to the above view. Thanks a lot for replys in advance!

**EDIT:** MainActivity

```
public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View rateView = new RateView(this, null);
    setContentView(rateView);
 }
}
```

**EDIT:** MainActivity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainScreen"
android:background="#da5f02">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Picture"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="#da5f02"
    android:src="@drawable/monalisa"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainScreen"
android:background="#da5f02">

 <com.yourpackage.RateView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Picture"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="#da5f02"
    android:src="@drawable/monalisa"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please look at this

public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View rateView = new RateView(this, null);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
}
```

Comment: How you then access this ImageView inside onDraw function? It's still not showing since the 2nd interation of onDraw overrides it.

Comment: you can not access imageview in onDraw ,it must be set by activity

Comment: view will be used to draw things and xml thing will be used for setting image

Comment: The only way this ImageView is shown is if i change contentView to my main activity and not costum view. As soon as I set contentView to costum view RateView the entire xml layout disappears and gets overriden somehow.

Comment: Check it now you are not inflating layout in contentView use above activity_main

Comment: Add your view in activity_main and inflate activity_main using MainActivity.

Comment: IT WORKS! This was the problem, was inflating the costum view instead of the activity. Thanks a lot, trully appreciated!

Comment: Put a tick mark to answer so that other can also look into it . Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you will Custom view then you can add only one background for View so you should change your approach for above achievement.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RateView extends View
```

Add this view in Activity/Fragment 
In activity_main put

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
     <ImageView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="5dp"
          android:src="@drawable/image" />

            <com.yourpackage.RateView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

add image here view can not add image.

Comment: That's what I've done initially. I did put that in layout\main_screen.xml which is xml of my main activity but my costum view then overrides this ImageView, therefore it's not shown,

Comment: Eddited above and added everything.